# HDD -> SSD Clone [Insufficent storage]

Tags: windows-7, ssd, clone

I'm cloning a HDD with Windows 7 to SSD with "sector by sector clone", but I'm having insufficient storage error. It only shows when I tick "sector by sector clone". How do I solve this?

I already cloned the HDD to the SSD without sector by sector clone, but was having issues booting. I was told online sector by sector is required.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The source drive is bigger than the target drive. You will need to change the partition size to be equal to or smaller than the target drive.

Comment: Am I able to do that without corrupting the source drive? My OS and all my personal files are currently stored on it.

Comment: You need something like this. https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html

Answer (score 0):

Your source partition is larger then your target position, so you can't clone it this way.   (You have not mentioned the make of drive, but some reputable companies offer tools to do what you are trying to do) - otherwise you need to go through the laborious process of shrinking the disk first.